# How to convert ImageIcon to Image?

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I have grabbed the imageicon from my project src files like this:

```
 icon = new ImageIcon(ViewDetailsV.class.getResource("/brandnew/images/male_avatar.jpg"));
```

Then I want to put into this line so as to resize to the size of the label:

```
lblPhotoField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ScaledImage(icon, lblPhotoField.getWidth(), lblPhotoField.getHeight()));
```

But I need the "icon" to be image , not imageicon as the method ScaledImage takes in Image parameter instead of ImageIcon.

```
 private Image ScaledImage(Image img, int w, int h){
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(img, 0,0,w,h,null);
    g2.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
}
```

Yup I did tried changing the return value to ImageIcon but it gave me errors. So I'm now focusing on how to convert ImageIcon to Image so I can put it in the method line, getting the icon and set my label it like this:

```
 lblPhotoField.setIcon(icon);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`ImageIcon#getImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage%28%29) method...

```
ScaledImage(icon.getImage(), lblPhotoField.getWidth(), lblPhotoField.getHeight())
```

Unless you are setting the size of the `lblPhotoField` you're self (which in of it self is worrisome) or it has already being laid out, I wouldn't rely on the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`

Comment: oh.. then what do you suggest? :D

Comment: Define a "preferred" size of the photo and let the layout manager deal with the rest, unless you are trying to scale the image if the label changes, then that's a different kettle of fish

Comment: Yup! I'm trying to scale the image if the label changes :D Thanks for your help! Then again, please help out in my next question? :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570245/maximum-length-of-jtextfield-and-only-accepts-numbers

Comment: It might be easier to create a custom component that simply knows how to scale the image and paint it.  Take a look at [maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) for an example